# Exception in java project [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON]

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:151)
    at com.erp.utility.Hibernatesession.getSession(Hibernatesession.java:24)
    at com.erp.dao.Country_Dao.getcountryByname(Country_Dao.java:88)
    at com.erp.service.Country_Service.getcountryByname(Country_Service.java:36)
    at com.erp.storedata.Store_Data.main(Store_Data.java:24)
```

Comment: Only exception message without the code is not that much helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Use a newer version of the slf4j-api.jar. There was a breaking change between version 1.5.5 and earlier and 1.5.6 and later. Use a version after 1.5.6, and that error should go away. For reference, see http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#IllegalAccessError.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following file on your project:

```
slf4j-log4j12.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the file slf4j-api.jar from your build path.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this problem in my SpringBoot application. If updating version is not helping this might help. Sometimes other libraries might bring different versions of this dependencies. These are the steps:

1. By error stack trace figure out which dependency is giving this issue
2. Get maven dependency plugin tree. Using this tree details find out if this library is coming as part of the some other dependency. In my case, the `logback-classic` and `log4j-over-slf4j` were giving this problem. They came together under `spring-boot-starter-web`
3. Use `<exclusions><exclusion></exclusion></exclusions>` in your `pom.xml` in that dependency for the libraries that giving this issue. In my case it looks like this:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

References: 
http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#IllegalAccessError 
http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings